# iframe scroll bars on iPad

Tags: ipad, frames

I have a couple of iframes positioned absolutely (left and right).

In all desktop browsers they appear correctly in height and with scroll bars.

On the iPad there are no scrollbars and they just extend the full height of their content.

Any ideas?

```
<iframe src="/solutions/pcc/builder/picker.asp" id="iframepicker" name="iframepicker"></iframe>  
<iframe src="work.asp" id="iframesurvey" name="iframesurvey" onload="frameisloaded(this)"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#iframepicker,#iframesurvey{
    width:48%;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    height:85%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding:2px;
}
#iframepicker{
    left:14px;
    border:1px solid #0066cc;
}
#iframesurvey{
    right:12px;
    border:1px solid #006638;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on the iPad there are no scroll bars. You use two fingers to scroll. Perhaps you already knew this, but just in case you're expecting scroll bars I just wanted to let you know that you're never going to see any scroll bars on the iPad.

If it isn't just that you're missing the scroll bars and the content actually extends to the full height, I would try to use fixed size instead of %. Perhaps the iPad just disregards the % and just uses the full height of the content.

Comment: yes it does display the full content though of course this means that you end up with two "iframes" of different extents

Comment: I'm not sure why this was the accepted answer.  Using a fixed size doesn't work either.  It always displays the full height of the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can get scroll bars on the iPad. Whoever says ipads don't have scrollbars is wrong.

Native to ios5 you can add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; You need a height defined though. This will allow you to do the single finger swipe and have a scroll bar appear as you are scrolling. It will vanish once your scroll is complete. In addition, I have also had problems with this CSS rule on pages with iframes... I hope it works for you though!